# Swift 2 using Parse : could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' to 'NSNumber'

Tags: swift, parse-platform, numbers, nsarray, nsnumber

i try to modify an array in parse using swift 2, i don't have anny issue when i build the app but when i touch the button linked to the action i got this error (see below). I already tried to modify my code using kcurrentUser or different things like that but i always get the same issue ..

`Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x10f4d58d8) to 'NSNumber' (0x10f8c7278).(lldb)`

Here's my code:

```
PFUser.currentUser().addObject([kCurrentUser.objectForKey("Participations") as! Int + 1], forKey: "Participations")
```

Answer (score 0):

The object for your key "Participation" is an array. You are trying to cast it as an Int.

Comment: Is the Participation property an array of integers or one integer? (it says on the Parse dashboard). If it is an integer, you need to use `PFUser.currentUser()["Participations"] = (kCurrentUser.objectForKey("Participations") as! Int + 1)`.